# Expandable listview with 2 TextViews in grouprow xml

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have a curious problem and this is my third day of trawling StackOverflow and Google,looking for an answer.all ive got is a headache so far :) 
I'm still a newbie so forgive the question.

I'm creating an app that summarizes expenditure by year,month and category (ie groceries,rent etc). I want to Display this data using an ExpandableListview in the following fashion

```
Year:2013 ------Total Spent 1,234.56 Total Income: 7,890.11 (this is the group header)
    Apr: Spent 4,000.00 ------Recv: 6,0000 (child rows opened on clicking header)
    Mar: Spent 3,500.00 ------Recv: 5,0000
    Feb: Spent 2,000.00 ------Recv: 4,0000
    Jan: Spent 1,500.00 ------Recv: 3,0000
```

Finally on clicking any of these children the user would be transported to a page showing how the amounts came to be by category.

The question:  Is there a way of displaying

```
Year:2013 ------Total Spent 1,234.56 Total Income: 7,890.11
```

in the header group row? if so how would the group xml look like.

Ive tried the following as the grouprow header but the app just crashes on startup. i figure that you can only have a single text item in the grouprow header. infact even trying to put a Relative etc Layout just crashes even if only a single text item is described in the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
    <CheckedTextView
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/green_check"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtYear"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Year"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|top"
        android:height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/txtSentAmountYr"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:numeric="decimal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Total Sent"
        android:textColor="#442a8d" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|top"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtRecvdAmountYr"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtYear"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtYear"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSentAmountYr"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:numeric="decimal"
        android:text="Total Received"
        android:textColor="#28a928"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If its not possible i'm thinking of using a TableLayout with texts etc to do the same thing. however an Expandable listview is great for visual and realEstate purposes.
Thanks Dev's

---

### New question

I've managed to adopt the answers provided by Krishna and JFrankie. I however ended up with a new set of issues :(

I have a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter so that i can modify my header views.

Because of this, i'm having a big issue displaying data from the database because in order to retrieve from DB as per all the examples ive seen, you need to extend SimpleCursorTreeAdapter. (and i dont know if you can extend your class by 2 diff classes?)

I have tried a kludgy solution (as pasted below) which is miraculously working but returns only the header groups and no children. Actually it repeats the first record in the group over and over. (i'm glad to at least progressed thus far)

Question:

a. How do i use BaseExpandableListAdapter and SimpleCursorTreeAdapter in the same adapter? so that i can get my custom layout as well as read my data from DB?

b. I've gone through the samples ie ExpandableListView 1 and 2 by google but for a newbie there just arent enough dots to connect how to do a different implementation. 
Thanks to JFrankie whose code i studied to create the adapter.

heres the custom adapter

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapterCustom extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    protected Activity currentActivity;
    public ExpandableListViewAdapterCustom(Activity callingActivity){
    this.currentActivity = callingActivity;
    }

    private Cursor mGroupsCursorLocal ;
    private Cursor mChildCursor;
    private Context ctx;
    private int groupItem;
    private int childItem;
    private String[] fieldsToUseFromGroupCursor;
    private int[] screenTextsToMapGroupDataTo;
    private String[] fieldsToUseFromChildCursor;
    private int[] screenTextsToMapChildDataTo;

    public ArrayList<String> tempChild;
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;
    public int intGroupTotal;


    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void setCtx(Context ctx) {
       this.ctx = ctx;
    }

     public void setGroupItem(int groupItem) {
         this.groupItem = groupItem;
      }

    public void setChildItem(int childItem) {
        this.childItem = childItem;
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        return currentActivity;
    }

     public Cursor getmGroupsCursorLocal() {
        return mGroupsCursorLocal;
      }

    public Context getCtx() {
        return currentActivity.getBaseContext();
    }

    public void setmGroupsCursorLocal(Cursor mGroupsCursor) {
        this.mGroupsCursorLocal = mGroupsCursor;
    }

    public ExpandableListViewAdapterCustom(Cursor mGroupsCursor,
                                       Activity activity,
                                       int groupItem,
                                       int childItem,
                                       String[] fieldsToUseFromGroupCursor,
                                       int[] screenTextsToMapGroupDataTo,
                                       String[] fieldsToUseFromChildCursor,
                                       int[] screenTextsToMapChildDataTo) {



        DatabaseRoutines db = new DatabaseRoutines(activity);

        setmGroupsCursorLocal(mGroupsCursor);
        mGroupsCursorLocal = db.fetchGroup();
        activity.startManagingCursor (mGroupsCursor);
        mGroupsCursorLocal.moveToFirst();

        mChildCursor=db.fetchChildren(mGroupsCursorLocal.getColumnIndex("Year"));
        mChildCursor.moveToFirst();
        activity.startManagingCursor(mChildCursor);



        setCtx(activity);
        setCurrentActivity(activity);

        }

        public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
           return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
          return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, 
            int childPosition,boolean         
            isLastChild, 
            View convertView, 
            ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = convertView;
           if (v == null) 
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
       (LayoutInflater)     ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);            
       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_listview_childrow, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtMonth = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMonth);
        TextView txtMonthAmountSent = (TextView)
        v.findViewById(R.id.txtMonthAmountSentValue);
        TextView txtMonthReceived = (TextView)
        v.findViewById(R.id.txtMonthAmountReceivedValue);
        txtMonth.setText(mChildCursor.getString(mChildCursor.getColumnIndex("Month")));

    txtMonthAmountSent.setText
   (mChildCursor.getString(mChildCursor.getColumnIndex("TotalSent")));
    txtMonthReceived.setText

    (mChildCursor.getString(mChildCursor.getColumnIndex("TotalReceived")));
    return v;
     }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return (mChildCursor.getCount());
       }

    @Override
     public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
     return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
    return mGroupsCursorLocal.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
     public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(
       int groupPosition, 
       boolean isExpanded,
       View convertView,     
       ViewGroup parent) 
     {
         View v = convertView;
         if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  
        (LayoutInflater)  ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_listview_groupheader, parent, false);
       }

       TextView txtYear = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtYearValue);
       TextView txtAmountSent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAmountSentValue);
       TextView txtAmountRecieved = (TextView) 
       v.findViewById(R.id.txtAmountReceivedValue);

       txtYear.setText(mGroupsCursorLocal.getString(
       mGroupsCursorLocal.getColumnIndex("Year")));

       txtAmountSent.setText(
       mGroupsCursorLocal.getString(mGroupsCursorLocal.getColumnIndex("TotalSent")));

       txtAmountRecieved.setText(
      GroupsCursorLocal.getString(mGroupsCursorLocal.getColumnIndex("TotalReceived")));
      return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return false;
    }


}
```

The Database code is like this

```
public Cursor fetchGroup() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();  //if memory leaks check here
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT MIN(ID) AS id, 
    Year, SUM(SentAmount) AS    TotalSent, SUM(ReceivedAmount) AS TotalReceived 
     FROM  MyTbl GROUP BY Year ORDER BY Year DESC ";
      return db.rawQuery(query, null);}

public Cursor fetchChildren(int Yr) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); //if memory leaks check here
    String query = "SELECT  MIN(ID) AS id, 
    Year, Month, SUM(SentAmount) AS TotalSent, 
     SUM(ReceivedAmount) AS TotalReceived        
     FROM  MyTbl Where Year= "+ Yr +"   GROUP BY Year, 
     Month ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to implement your custom adapter and override the method getGroupView and inflate your layout?
You should sent the log so we can try to understand the error.
For example

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSentAmountYr"
```

isn't correct..remove the '+', alson in alignBottom and so on. 
If you want to have some info about creating a custom exapandable adapter give a look on my blog, [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want  to create a header view like this

```
Year:2013 ------Total Spent 1,234.56 Total Income: 7,890.11
```

Create a sample class extending BaseExpandableListAdapter  and  in the getGroupview

override method, use user layout for header  and in getChildview metho,use the  layout for

childs.

```
Note :     @Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return Size of Group item;
}
```

For better answer,provide logcat errors..